# Visual Studio debugger behaves incorrectly on .Any() in if statement

Tags: c#, visual-studio

When I debug this code in Visual Studio 2015/2017 the debugger steps into the `if` statement. Why is that? The code doesn't seem to execute though.

```
private static async Task Test()
{
    var somethingasync = await Task.FromResult(0);

    var list = Enumerable.Empty<object>();

    if (list.Any())
        ;   // This line is reached by the debugger (but is not executed)
}
```

If I put additional code after `if` the line is not reached.

```
private static async Task Test()
{
    var list = Enumerable.Empty<object>();

    if (list.Any())
        ;   // This line is not reached

    var foo = "bar";
}
```

If I assign `list.Any()` to a variable and check the variable, the line isn't reached:

```
private static async Task Test()
{
    var list = Enumerable.Empty<object>();

    var hasElements = list.Any();

    if (hasElements)
        ;   // Does not reach this line

    if (list.Any())
        ;   // This line is reached    
}
```

The issue occurs only when then method is async.

Comment: what do you mean by *reached by the debugger (but is not executed)*

Comment: Did you try cleaning your solution? Your code lines may not be in sync with the debugger lines (pdb file).

Comment: @Prajwal The line is highlighted with yellow background color when stepping with F11.

Comment: @Mixxiphoid I've created a new empty project.

Comment: Possibly what @Mixxiphoid said. Also there are times when I've faced some situation like this. I've fixed it by restarting VS. Couldn't find the reason though.

Comment: I've cleaned the solution and I've restarted VS and I've created new projects as well. Still error.

Comment: Is the Async task actually ever executed?

Comment: @Mixxiphoid Yes, it is. In this example I've replaced it with `await Task.FromResult(0);` though.

Comment: Is this the code you actually running?

Comment: @Reniuz This is a simplified example. The real code has other code in the `if` and the `var somethingasync` is a real async method call.

Comment: This may sound weird, but have you restarted your computer? I once had a bug where `if(ExpressionThatIsFalse) code;` actually got executed. This dissapeared after resetting the cache of visual studio and restarting my computer.

Comment: @Mixxiphoid Yes, I've restarted the computer. Same problem.